IntelliSense referring to wrong header file in emscripten cmake project
Emscripten helps out with SDL2. It comes with headers and prebuilt libraries if you add the -sUSE_SDL option. I want to build it myself using FetchContent (CMake) and add the include directories and libraries to the project myself. This works and I can build and run SDL succesfully, but my IntelliSense reads the wrong SDL.h. If I try to open the SDL.h that IntelliSense sees I get a file with one line: #error "To use the emscripten port of SDL use -sUSE_SDL or -sUSE_SDL=2"
As such my code compiles fine while my cpp files throws a lot of errors as it doesn't recognize any of the declared SDL functions and variables.
How can I make IntelliSense recognize the correct header?
